# Google Sheets: How to make a macro/script that, for all selected rows, inserts two rows beneath, then copies and pastes the content from the original?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

See header! I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to code or anything, but I work in Google Sheets. I have large sheets where, basically, I need to create two copies of each row. I do this for enough different sheets that it would really help to be able to run a macro/script that does this for me. The problem is, when I try to use the macro recorder, it just inserts, then copies and pastes, the "test" row I recorded the macro for. I need a macro that will duplicate all the rows I have selected. Thank you!!

Comment: could you share your spreadsheet with us? or a test spreadsheet

Comment: Sure! Thanks JSmith. I just made a little template. My work sheets look something like this, except they're usually between 3,000 and 10,000 rows, so manually inserting rows and duplicating the information is not feasible. Check out sheet1, which is what it looks like, and sheet2, which is what I would like the macro to turn it into: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Nqp4v28MFP4wcxd1q6cpvA0o30duS_i73pY_E59IuA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've just answered your question, please mark as answered if that solved your problem

Comment: I'm gonna be real with you man I have no idea how to read this

Comment: Just go inside the script and run the function

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function copyThreeTimes() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const range = ss.getRangeByName('source');
  const values = range.getValues();
  let destinationRange = ss.getRangeByName('destination');
  const destinationSheet = destinationRange.getSheet();
  const destinationValues = []
  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
    if (values[i][0]){
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        destinationValues.push(values[i]);
    }
  }
  const maxRows = destinationSheet.getMaxRows()
  destinationSheet.insertRowsAfter(maxRows, destinationValues.length);
  destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(maxRows + 1, 1, destinationValues.length, 3);
  destinationRange.setValues(destinationValues);
}
```

make usage of named range for your range.
Then get the values and skip the header.
Copy 3 times the value then reshape the destination range and paste the value.

[Here is my example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wtHKuwqbtxahN9ksk0IwMASgKUb6wE1teht_wrPkzq4/edit?usp=sharing)